# A Little Crossover Experiment

Tags: discussion

(I hope I'm not breaking any rules!)

Hey there!

I'm here coming from the Worldbuilding Exchange. We cover several topics about fantastic worlds and several forms of fiction.

I came here to invite you guys for something that may be a fun little crossover experiment!

[It's about cooking a dragon.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/63016/how-to-serve-your-dragon)

We could use some experienced and creative cooks on that one, so if you are felling a tad humorous and creative, think about giving it a go!

Comment: Meta has few rules. I actually have some small rep on Worldbuilding, so I'll check it out. :)

Comment: Gonna put this on hold since there's not really a question, no sense it sticking around looking for answers.